# php word Invalid image: zip:///tmp/php5dJhEJ#word//media/image4.png

Tags: php, phpword

As I am using
phpword to textualize a word
it shows
Invalid image: zip:///tmp/php5dJhEJ#word//media/image4.png

i expect the file to be loaded

some file work but most files show this error

is there any way to get sure that it will work with all documents

i used this file
and a very basic installation
Just composer install
in PHP laravel
using:

```php
$phpWord = PhpWordIOFactory::load($filePath);
```

the issue persists with most files with images

I tried to investigate the library code

and i am not sure
But having 3 "///" and "word//" instead of "word/" seems suspicious

I couldn't follow the code furthermore

also it is suspicious that it happens with most files

not all files

Maybe the source type of the image(link or from the device (embedded))

any help will be appreciated
Also if i should provide more details or code i will be happy to do

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @KenLee Done
let me know if i should provide more code 
i am using laravel and just installed via composer 
when  i load the file this error shows